# Let $f : (a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and diﬀerentiable on $(a,b)$ and diﬀerentiable at a point k. Does $\lim_{x\to k} f'(x)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'd like to prove that this proposition holds.
Is it enough to say that by supposition, $\displaystyle{f'(k)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(k+h)-f(k)}{h}}$ exists?
Then, how can we prove that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to k} f'(x)=f'(k)}$ from this proposition?

Comment: If $f$ is differentialbe at $k$, it is also continuous at $k$, so why would one write "continuous on $(a,b)\setminus k$. I am not sure that the question is correctly stated.

Comment: That sure is, I will edit the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If f is not differentiable, no... 
If $f$ is not differentiable at $k$, then no. For instance, take $x\mapsto|x|$.

Its derivative coincides with$\frac{|x|}{x}$ for every $x\in(a,b)\setminus \{0\}$, but is not defined in $0$. You can easily see that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}=\frac{x+h-x}{h}=1 \\
\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}=\frac{-x-h+x}{h}=-1
$$
so $\lim{x\to 0} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}|x|$ does not exist.

... but even if it is.

The hypothesis that also $f'(k)$ exists it still does not suffice.

The classic evil example is
$$
f(x)=x^2\sin \left (\frac{1}{x} \right) \qquad \textrm {for } x\neq 0
$$
and $f(0)=0$. If you differentiate this function you obtain
$$
f'(x)=2x\sin \left (\frac{1}{x} \right )-\cos \left ( \frac{1}{x} \right)  \qquad \textrm {for } x\neq 0
$$
and $f'(0)=0$. The bad news is that the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)
$$
does not exist.

Comment: It must be $2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Evil example indeed... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could be the statement true in $\mathbb{C}$? I think yes.

Comment: @Rafael Yes, indeed. A (complex) differentiable function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb C$ is $C^\infty$ as a consequence of Cauchy's representation. This guarantees the continuity of $f'$, hence the existence of the limit.